# i want to change my checkboxes

Tags: php, drupal, checkbox, drupal-7, watchdog

i have here some checkboxes with values of watchdog_severity:

```
    // Form for the severity checkboxes.
    $blabla_severity_levels = variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());

    // Declare empty options array.
    $blabla_severity_options = array();

    // Loop through each severity level and push to options array for form.
    foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $number_select => $severity) {
      $blabla_severity_options[$severity] = check_plain(drupal_ucfirst(
        $severity));
    }

    // Generate checkbox list for given severity levels.
    $blabla_form['blabla_severity'] = array(
      '#type'        => 'fieldset',
      '#title'       => t('Select the severity.'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed'   => TRUE,
    );

    $blabla_form['blabla_severity']['blabla_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $blabla_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($blabla_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );

    return system_settings_form($blabla_form);
```

ok now i call in my function that severity_levels:

```
function blabla_check_checkboxes() {
  $severity_levels = variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());
}
```

now if selct only the info checkbox and export the values of `$severity_levels` it gets me out something like this :

```
    info (String, 4 characters ) info
    emergency (Integer) 0
    alert (Integer) 0
    critical (Integer) 0
    error (Integer) 0
    warning (Integer) 0
    notice (Integer) 0
    debug (Integer) 0
```

but i want to export something like this in my function `blabla_check_checkboxes()` :

```
        info (Integer) 6
        emergency (Integer) 0
        alert (Integer) 0
        critical (Integer) 0
        error (Integer) 0
        warning (Integer) 0
        notice (Integer) 0
        debug (Integer) 0
```

where 6 is the number of the drupal severity info...
Could someone help with that issue plz??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution may be to amend your functions in order to return the desired structure:

```
function blabla_check_checkboxes() {
  $orig_severity_levels = watchdog_severity_levels();
  $blabla_severity_levels = variable_get('blabla_severity_levels', array());
  foreach ($blabla_severity_levels as $level => $name) {
    if ((int) $name) {
      $blabla_severity_levels[$level] = $orig_severity_levels[$level];
    }
  }
  return $blabla_severity_levels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using [system_settings_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form_submit/7) - this function will save only the array keys.

You need to find a workaround like having your additional submit function or having a wrapper function for retrieving this structured array.

In this case, you try to overuse the checkboxes initial scope.

Comment: I did it and it shows me :6 (String, 4 characters ) 6,
    0 (Integer) 0,
    1 (Integer) 0,
    2 (Integer) 0,
    3 (Integer) 0,
    4 (Integer) 0,
    5 (Integer) 0,
    7 (Integer) 0,

Comment: thanks for your reply i really need to solve this problem... : / : / : /

Comment: could you write me some code that will help me more plz?? I am new in coding generally